# Как построить сложное предложение с различными видами связи?

Tags: синтаксис, редактура

С ней он словно бы играл роль доброго дядюшки, который очень редко заходит в дом к дальним родственникам, и, потому что визиты коротки и непродолжительны, ему удивительно неловко и словно бы даже стыдно, что он не оказывает должного влияния на младшее поколение, и оно таким образом совершенно распоясалось и теперь не соответствует нич(ь)ему, в первую очередь — дядюшкиному о нем представлению.

Как вы считаете, есть ли смысл в этом предложении? А если он все-таки есть, то как вправить такому предложению суставы?

Comment: Прежде всего, мешает первое "бы" и вызывает вопросы сочетание "короткие и непродолжительные".

Answer (score 2):

С ней он словно бы играл роль доброго дядюшки, который очень редко заходит к дальним родственникам в дом, а так как визиты коротки и непродолжительны, ему удивительно неловко и вроде бы  даже стыдно, что он не оказывает должного влияния на младшее поколение, — и оно таким образом совершенно распоясалось и теперь не соответствует ничьему, и в первую очередь дядюшкиному о нем представлению.

Answer (score 1):

С ней он будто играл роль доброго дядюшки, который очень редко заходит к дальним родственникам, и которому от непродолжительности его визитов удивительно неловко и как бы даже стыдно, что не оказывает он должного влияния на младшее поколение, - ведь оно от этого совершенно распоясалось и уже не соответствует чьему-либо и особенно дядюшкиному о нём представлению.